# Validation of radiation detectors by comparison with Gamma - spectrometer

Tags: spectroscopy, particle-detectors

Good day! 
The title states what I am trying to do. I have a Cs-137 source with total activity of 3,7MBq (not much else is stated on the protective container). I would like to measure this source with a hand-held contamination monitor ("Berthold Tech. LB-124") and then compare the result with the spectrometer's result.

And then started the problems. I can't trust either of the results; the LB-124 gives a value in $\frac{Bq}{cm^2}$ (I don't have the necessary information to convert to Bq and I am NOT going to take a ruler to the source, since the activity is very large). After measuring the source (with set nucleus Cs-137+)  it gave a value of $\sim 50 \frac{Bq}{cm^2}$ and gross $ \sim 2800cps$ both of these seem much too low (I understand that the detector has a low efficiency but shouldn't the nuclide specific efficiency factor correct that?).
If I set the LB-124 to beta/gamma channel total cps value than it doesn't use any source specific efficiency factor and (as I understand) the counts shown are only the ones that hit the detector, whilst everything else is not taken into account.
The spectrometer gave a dead time value of 71%, measured time = 120s, real time = ~409s. I got a couple of peaks: the largest was auto-identified as Cs-137 at 661,66KeV and the counts at peak max height was around 300 000 counts. 
Some simple math gives: $\frac{300 000}{120} = 2500cps$ (so I guess the two instruments agree?)

But I suspect it would be better to compare the Bq values?
So I need the spectrometer to calculate activity, for this it needs an efficiency curve. I am using "SpectraLine GP" software, it has a built in eff. calculator. I follow the manual as best I can (even so some of the functions just don't work as described and all in all the experience has not been user friendly), using manual data input I give it the sources factual value and tell it to calculate efficiency for all the found peaks (some times it complies other times it does nothing), but so far it has agreed to calculate for 6 out of 9 peaks (no idea why it excludes some). After this I use the activity function. It gives me a nice results tab with 661KeV identified as Cs-137 and an activity value of 906Bq (definitely not correct); the rest of the peaks are unidentified and thus not calculated (one time it thought that some of the peaks were Co-60).

I hope that someone who understands what I am saying will read this and give me some pointers.
I suspect that I am not using the efficiency calculator properly: there is an option to set zones for the efficiency curve and their power levels (number of data points - peaks must be more than zones). Maybe some one can explain how to set those zones?

To sum up, this is what I have:
 - Actual activity = 3,7MBq

- LB124 gives $50 \frac{Bq}{cm^2}$  and 2800cps gross value.

I use some guessing and figure that the sources' surface area might be $50cm^2$ so $50 \cdot 50 = 2500Bq$ or cps (since the eff. factor has been applied the Bq and cps value should be the same?).

The spectrometer tells me that the biggest peak (661KeV) is Cs-137 and that during 120s of measuring it accumulated 300 000 events. Divide that value by time (120s) and get 2500cps again. Is this a good agreement?

Comment: Note - the activity level on the source should have a date associated with it. The half life of Cs-137 is about 30 years which is fairly good - but if you have had the source since the 1950's it would matter... You really need to pay careful attention to the source configuration (including everything that can attenuate and scatter) if you want to make sense of this. And 3.7 MBq is 0.1 mCi - during imaging exams, people are routinely injected with 10 mCi and more; I would not be too worried about (briefly) measuring the distance accurately with a ruler, the dose you will get is minimal.

Comment: Can you explain what your ultimate goal is? Are you trying to make sure you understand the readings of the LB124?

Comment: I was unable to find any date associated with the activity value; but the source is definitely fairly new (we purchased it this year).  My ultimate goal is to develop some method to routinely check that the LB124 is in good working condition, by comparing it with the spectrometer. And yes I would also like to be sure that I understand how the device works internally (with regard to conversion coefficients and given values cps; Bq/cm^2). As well as to be able to calculate source activity from spectrum (If you can explain how to do that manually I would also be very grateful).

Comment: You may have one or more misunderstandings here. First, the areal units from your handheld monitor are not the area of the source, they are the exposed area. Second what is the relationship between 'the spectrometer' and the handheld meter? Third the expected count rate on your monitor depends on the distance from the source (and some geometric factors that can be ignored if that distance is much larger than the source).

Comment: Finally, the half life of Cs-137 is fairly long on human timescales (about 30 years), but not so long that you can ignore it over year long timescales if you want percent scale precision: in short you really need to know the start-date for the quoted activity.

Comment: Thank you very much for your replies! I am glad to see such a responsive community.
It seems that I should have been more clear on my goals.
I would like to reiterate: i need to compere the measurement results of the two devices. I work at a laboratory and wee need to document routine checks of our instruments.

Comment: @dmckee You raise some very good points. I realize the significance of distance, source geometry and other parameters in acquiring the activity value of the source.
The contamination monitor has a detection area of roughly 200x180 (mm). I held it as close to the source as possible (almost touching it, parallel to height axis), for about 120sec. I guessed that the surface area of the object was about 50cm^2... thus giving me the total activity?